# MockitoExtension doesn't init mocks for scala tests

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

I am using @ExtendWith(Array(classOf[MockitoExtension])) in test class that extends FlatSpec, And my tests failed because my mocks don't initialized between the test (Both from IntelliJ and sbt test) I am sure I am doing something wrong but I am not sure what... 
Here is my code:

```
@ExtendWith(Array(classOf[MockitoExtension]))
class Mytests extends FlatSpec with MockitoSugar with ReadFuture with BeforeAndAfter {
  private val myMockcache = mock[...]
  val underTest = new testClass(myMockcache)

  it should "return result with error if myMockcache.invalidateIfPresent throw exception" in {
    when(myMockcache.invalidateIfPresent(..., ...)).thenThrow(ex)
    readFuture(underTest.doSomthing(...)) shouldBe ItemResult(None, error = Some(ex))
  }

  it should "update the cache" in {
    readFuture(underTest.doSomthing(...)) shouldBe ItemResult(Some(...), error = None)
  }
}
```

I am using  mockito-junit-jupiter-2.28.2

Thanks

Comment: JUnit extensions are not supported by Scalatest ATM - see https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/1454

Comment: However, what you want to achieve can be done with fixtures - http://doc.scalatest.org/1.7.2/org/scalatest/fixture/FlatSpec.html